# Dynamic fgets in C

Tags: c, reinventing-the-wheel, io

I wanted to make a function that will dynamically retrieve a line from a stream to a buffer. This function just needs to take in the `char*` and the stream to read from. It'll keep allocating a bigger buffer until it can read all the data into the `rtr` variable (terminated on new line). Any ways I can improve this would be amazing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char* dynamic_fgets(char** rtr, FILE* stream) {
    int bufsize = 1024; //Start at 1024 bytes
    char* buf = (char*) malloc(bufsize*sizeof(char));

    if(buf == NULL) {
        perror("Couldn't allocate memory for buf in dynamic_fgets\n");
    }

    do {
        fgets(buf, bufsize, stream);
        *rtr = realloc(*rtr, strlen(buf)+strlen(*rtr));
        if(*rtr == NULL) {
            perror("Couldn't allocate memory for *rtr in dynamic_fgets\n");
        }

        *rtr = strncat(*rtr, buf, bufsize);
        bufsize *= 2;
    } while(buf[strlen(buf)-1] != '\n');

    return *rtr;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    char* buf = (char*) malloc(sizeof(1));
    strncpy(buf, "\0", 1);
    printf("Input:  ");

    dynamic_fgets(&buf, stdin);

    printf("Output:  %s", buf);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you want [getline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) ?

Answer (score 10):

**Code runs into *undefined behavior* (UB)**

Code fails to test the return value of `fgets()`.  Without knowing the return value is not `NULL`, `strlen(buf)` can get called on 1) uninitialized memory or 2) memory in an undefined state or 3) `buf[]` from the previous `fgets()` call.

```
// UB possible
fgets(buf, bufsize, stream);
*rtr = realloc(*rtr, strlen(buf)+strlen(*rtr));

// Better
if (fgets(buf, bufsize, stream)) {
  ... strlen(buf) ...
```

**Infinite loop**

Should user input end with a non-`'\n'`  (think piped input), `do` loop does not stop before UB kicks in.

**Exploitable code**

`dynamic_fgets(&buf, stdin);` allows an external user make the program use excessive  resources.  There is no  upper bound.  Defensive coding does not allow memory consumption to go unchecked from potential hostile users or pathological file input.

IMO, `dynamic_fgets()` , deserves an upper bound parameter.  Once exceeded, the routine should not allocative more memory and instead return an error indication.

**Code is fooled with `'\0'`**

How robust do you want your code?

In hostile cases, `fgets()` may read a *null character* and `fgets()` treats it no different than any other non `'\n'` character.  A following `strlen(buf)` can stop on the usual null character *appended* by `fgets()`, yet it will first stop on a *read* null character.  `strlen(buf)` could be `0` due to such input.

Further this code is then readily exploitable due to `buf[strlen(buf)-1]` by entering a *null character* as the first input character.  The code is the same as `buf[SIZE_MAX]` an access outside the allocation and thus UB.  At a minimum, do not code `buf[strlen(buf)-1]` when `buf[0] == 0` is possible.

**`size_t` vs. `int`**

Minor: `size_t` is the right width for array sizing.  It is the type return by `strlen()` and accepted by `*alloc()`.  `int` can be insufficient for long strings.

Comment: `Code is fooled with '\0'` is an interesting exploit indeed.

Answer (score 8):

- Make up your mind. `dynamic_fgets` returns the same information via return value (`return *rtr`) and the in-out parameter (`char ** rtr`). Chose one.
- Do not cast `malloc` return value. In C it is redundant, and may cause hard-to-find bugs.

  If, for any reason, you feel you need to cast it, be consistent and cast `realloc` as well.

  Ditto for `sizeof(char)`. It is 1 by definition; if you still want to spell it out in a call to `malloc`, do so for `realloc`.
- `*rtr = realloc(*rtr, ....)` is dangerous, for it leads to memory leak. Shall `realloc` fail, the memory pointed by `*rtr` prior to the call is lost. Consider instead

  ```
  char * tmp = realloc(*rtr, ....);
  if (tmp == NULL) {
      // whatever recovery strategy you may come up with, e.g. free(*rtr);
      ....
      return error_indication;
  }
  *rtr = tmp;
  .... // Business as usual
  ```
- Every call to `dynamic_fgets` allocates 1024 bytes for `buf`, which is never `free`d. 1024 bytes per call leaked.
- An unconditional reallocation looks strange. Chances are that what `fgets` have read is fitting into an allocated space just fine. Consider testing for `\n` first, and `realloc` only if necessary.
- `strncat(*rtr, buf, bufsize)` must find a terminating `\0` in a memory pointed by `*rtr`, which leads to quadratic time complexity. You should track where the terminator was placed by the previous iteration.
- `buf` is unnecessary. You may read directly into `*rtr` (plus offset, see the above bullet), thus sparing a copy.

Answer (score 6):

I suggest using the [POSIX `getline()` function](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) as it does what the posted code is trying to do.  However, it does take a third parameter (a pointer to a variable to receive the length of the read line). It also returns the number of bytes read (or an EOF indicator).

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the suggestion, but I wanted to make something myself so I could understand the language better

Comment: @AxelPersinger Even if you want to implement something from scratch, it's still a good idea to learn from the design of existing solutions. In particular, the second parameter and the return value differ from yours, and you should consider why.

Answer (score 4):

#### Bug: buffer overflow

You only ever allocate `buf` once, with size `1024`, here:

> ```
> int bufsize = 1024; //Start at 1024 bytes
> char* buf = (char*) malloc(bufsize*sizeof(char));
> ```

But later, you double `bufsize` on every iteration through the loop, without also doubling the allocation of `buf`.

Therefore, on the second iteration of the loop, when you run this line:

> ```
>     fgets(buf, bufsize, stream);
> ```

you will overflow your buffer, because `buf` has `1024` bytes, but `bufsize` will be `2048`.  As user vnp mentioned, you don't really even need the `buf` variable if you just read to the end of `*rtr` and keep track of the number of bytes read so far.

#### Shlemiel the painter

There is a [funny story](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2001/12/11/back-to-basics/) about a painter who paints slower and slower every day.  The punchline:

> "I can't help it," says Shlemiel. "Every day I get farther and farther
>   away from the paint can!"

This story is actually about concatenating strings.  In your loop, there are the following operations:

```
strlen(buf) x2
strlen(*rtr)
strncat(*rtr)
```

You can't avoid one call to `strlen(buf)` but the calls involving `rtr` can be avoided by simply tracking the length of `rtr` in some variable.

Answer (score 3):

One more thing not mentioned yet. Dont put command line arguments if you dont use them in the code. It is just misleading since you dont use `argc` and `argv`. consider to use simply `int main (void)`

Comment: Shouldn't that be `int main(void)`?

Comment: you are right in c++ its without the void but not in c. i will edit it. see https://www.google.de/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-int-main-int-mainvoid/amp/